# VB.Net: Replace special characters like "_x000D_" with their equivalent values within a string

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, replace

I am uploading a few free-text values from an Excel spreadsheet into my VB.NET project and saving values in the SQL server database.
But a few special characters like `_x000D_` were saved into the database (they weren't visible in Excel spreadsheet).

How can this be converted to its original values before saving them into the database?

I thought to replace them using the `Replace("_x000D_", vbcrlf)` function, but I am not sure if there would be any other special characters (and their equivalent values in VB.Net)?

Answer (score -1):

Your spreadsheet contains a cell having a content that includes multiples lines of text. This is a common situation. Another special char that can occur more often is `TAB (0x09)`.Other chars that can appear inside the text depends too much by your spreadsheet content and I cannot give you a list. 
Replacing them is a good solution. If you suspect that there are more than those two chars, you can make a generic replace function that extracts the hexa code from the string and replace it with the corresponding char converted from the hexa code.